# Network Manager: full internet access, but through which device/connection

Tags: networkmanager

The command

```
nmcli connectivity check
```

can tell whether the computer is connected to the internet, or (only) to a local network. Is there a way to obtain information about the connectivity *through a specific connection/device*? For example, suppose I am connected to the internet via a wireless connection and to a local network via a wired connection, is there a way to get this information from Network Manager?

Eventually I would like to make a script which does something to the devices not connected to the internet (e.g. power them off), whilst leaving the device connected to the internet intact.

Comment: Just type `nmcli` to see the required information.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I see no information which distinguishes devices connected to a local network from devices connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the command `ip`:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8
via x.y.u.o dev p3p1 src a.b.c.d 
cache
```

this command will indicate the device use as default gateway except if you add a static route for `8.8.8.8`.